# Module parse failed: Unexpected token . You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

What is this syntax `message?.length === 1` can anyone explain me how to convert it into normal javascript?

[image]

It is a vue js component I downloaded from somewhere but when I put into my project it gets an error

Answer (score 0):

`a?.b` is the "optional chaining" operator, which returns undefined when one of the chained properties is undefined or null.

`message?.length === 1` could be replaced by `message && message.length === 1`.